# Unable to update in Linux Mint 10 - Julia (Maverick)

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I just did a fresh installation of Linux Mint 10 and tried to do update or do any installation from Software Manager for that matter. But it just 404 out.

Any solution for this

Answer (score 1):

Linux Mint 10 is quite old (they're at release 16 now), it's been obsoleted since April 2012. See [this page](http://www.linuxmint.com/oldreleases.php) for a list of the Linux Mint releases.

So the solution is to pick a newer version of Linux Mint.

Comment: I am aware of the fact. thank you. I have chosen mint 10 because of my hardware limitations. I believe the newer versions need more resources that I am not able to provide.

Comment: Older does not automatically mean that it uses less resources. It mostly means it has more bugs and lacks security updates. If you have limited resources, consider which applications you run, and especially consider using a lighter desktop environment (not KDE or Gnome).